# latexindent with arara produces error message

Tags: texmaker, arara, java, latexindent

I try to get my files indented automatically with arara, latexindent and texmaker. 
I have the TexLive Distribution, so both programs should be installed correctly (or am I wrong?). At least when I start them over commandline, I get response:

```
  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

arara 3.0a - The cool TeX automation tool
Copyright (c) 2012, Paulo Roberto Massa Cereda
All rights reserved.
```

... and ...

```
latexindent.pl version 3.3, 2017-08-21
usage: latexindent.pl [options] [file][.tex|.sty|.cls|.bib|...]
```

...
So far so good. With my own command in Texmaker (arara %.tex) I just don't get it to run properly. When I tested `%arara: pdflatex`, it worked fine, but `%arara: indent: {overwrite:yes, trace:yes}` always gives me the following error message:

```
C:\texlive\2017\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:711: command failed with exit code 1: java.exe -jar c:\texlive\2017\texmf-dist\scripts\arara\arara.jar indent_test.tex
```

Since the `pdflatex` example worked, the problem should be latexindent. But what exactly is the problem?
Do I have to install a special pearl environment?

Thanks in advance!
Frieder

Comment: Have you got the latest version of indent.yaml from https://github.com/cereda/arara/tree/master/rules

Comment: Does latexindent.exe work from the command line? E.g. latexindent.exe myfile.tex

Comment: @cmhughes yes, I put the file in the following directory: C:\texlive\2017\texmf-dist\scripts\arara\rules

Comment: @cmhughes it actually worked over command line! So there should be a way to get it work properly in texmaker

Comment: @cmhughes: the rule from GitHub won't work because it's for version `4.0`. Gimme some time and I will try to rewrite it for version `3.0`, if possible. That might be the culprit.

Comment: @Wulle: can I take a look at your `indent.yaml` rule? What does it happen when you have `% arara: indent` without any parameters?

Comment: I tried to update a (to some extend) version 3.0 compilant rule for `indent.yaml`: https://gist.github.com/cereda/3ccdfb6257e5272ad9c1080a89c9ae9b Could you try with this one?

Comment: voting to close as Paulo and I have commented on this, and haven't had response from the OP

Comment: @cmhughes I am running `latexindent` on Windows 10 through MiKTeX, but I got this error `Can't locate Log/Log4perl.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Log::Log4perl module)`. Would you please tell me what to install knowing that I have strawberry installed?

Comment: Sure, see http://latexindentpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/appendices.html#module-installer-script